# Joomla 3: Remove unwanted html code from text

Tags: html, joomla

I have a joomla website that I just migrated from HTML. There are 1000s of articles and they contain unwanted HTML code in each, like you can see below.
How can i get rid of HTML in those articles without having to open each to edit?

```
 <div id="mainDIV">
<div id="topDIV">
<div id="topnav">
<div>
<div id="topnavdiv0"> </div>
<div id="topnavdiv"><a href="../store/">SHOP NOW</a> <img title="" src="images/shop-basket.gif" />  |  1-800-336-1630</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"> </div>

<table id="mainBody" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="left"> </td>
<td id="mid"><!-- top -->
<div id="top1">
<div id="bbb-logo"><a href="http://app.southeasttexas.bbb.org/report/10014674/"><img src="images/logo-bbb.gif" alt="metal-market-report-02-27-12" /></a></div>
</div>
<!--div id="top2"></div-->
<div id="flashnav"> </div>
<div id="topsep"> </div>
<!-- top --> <!-- content -->
<table id="contentBody">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="contentSep"> </td>
<td id="contentLeft">
<div id="titleBGlong">Metals Market Reports</div>
<br />
```

I really wish I don't have to come back and ask the same question again but I keep gettting error even after removing all ;
Please see error below:

```html
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 1
STR: <?
SQL: <?php
$query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM th18k_content WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 50');

SQL query: Documentation

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?php
$query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM th18k_content WHERE id BETWEEN' at line 1
```

Comment: You mean you're looking for some kind of HTML editor to help you with that?

Comment: Joomla articles are also stored as HTML. Obviously you don't want to remove all of it. Is the unwanted portion identical for each article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to get rid of the HTML tags in your articles? First find in what table are those articles stored in your database, then just fetch them and go through them using

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM th18k_content WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 50');
                                              //get articles from database
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { //for each article
  $lines = explode('\n',$row['article']);                      //split it into lines
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($lines);$i++)                     //so we can remove
  {                                            //the ones that we don't need
    if(strpos($line,'titleBGlong') === false) //if 'titleBGlong' isn't found...
    {
      unset($lines[$i]);                       //remove the line
    }
    else 
    {
      $newarticle = implode('\n',$lines);     //else put it back together
      break;                                  //and exit the loop
    }                          //now the $newarticle has the beginning removed
  }
  $strippedarticle = strip_tags($newarticle );//remove HTML tags
  mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE th18k_content SET article = "'.$strippedarticle.'" WHERE id = '.$row['id']);
}                                             //replace the article in the db
?>
```

I don't know what exactly are your database columns and table called, so you will need to change it. Also I did it between 0 and 50 because you may flood the database with queries because each article requires 2 queries (just run the code, change to next 50 and run it again, and so on)

@EDIT
The script can be run by saving it in .php file on the server and running it like a normal website page (I didn't connect to the database in this example)

which will get rid of all the lines until the "titleBGlong" is found, then you can use strip_tags to remove the tags

Comment: Joomla articles are stored in the database ;)

Comment: Thank you Mateusz, but I don't know how to use strip_tags($string); Can you please explain in details.

Comment: strip_tags basically removes all html tags, eg. `<div>` and leaves only plain text. I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you but I want to keep some of the code just to remove the top code in each article. How can I get that done please?

Comment: What part do you want to remove and what to keep? You didn't specify and I assumed that you want to get rid of all the html tags. Do you want to keep the mainBody table only? or only it's contents?

Comment: Thank you Mateusz, Where do I run the last script you sent please?

Comment: Do you know any PHP? because if you don't then it might be bit confusing, because the whole thing is pretty much a script. Do you have database connection estabilished? from what I've found out the table with articles in Joomla is called jos_content but I am not sure of the column names. I will rewrite the code so it is in one chunk and comment it so it is more clear :)

Comment: Yes, I know php and I have ran it using my table name which is `th18k_content` but I got error when I tried it. Please send your own script as said. Thank you very much. i really appreciate your kindness.

Comment: No bother :) I am here to help! What was the error? Did you change the table column names (id,article) to your names? Also there was an error in the line `$lines = explode('\n',$string);` and I just fixed it, don't know how did I miss it. I am getting ready for work, but I will try to find some free time to answer any questions :) (using mobile unfortunately, but I hope it will be possible). I am writing this code from my head, it should work, but I can't check it anyhow so just tell me what's going on :)

Comment: Please also provide either `mysqli`, `pdo` or Joomla API based database queries. never `mysql_*`

Comment: I get this error: "SQL query: Documentation

<?php $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM th18k_content where id BETWEEN 0 AND 50');

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?php
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM th18k_content where id BETWEEN 0 AND ' at line 1 "

Comment: @AdeolaAdeoti maybe it's because you need to use mysqli instead of mysql or it needs a semicolon. where isn't capitalised but it doesn't matter. I changed the code in my post to mysqli (notice the $con variables holding the connection, you might want to add mysqli_connect if it's not already there)

Comment: I ran this and every column went empty.

Comment: :O I hope you had a backup since you moved it not that long time ago. It is deleting all the lines up to "titleBGlong", are you sure that html is same in all of the articles and that the line is exactly like this? Try to run it once and print the result instead of putting it back in the database and see if it prints anything. The code had a flaw that if there is no "titleBGlong" all lines will be deleted, but I assumed it is there in every article. Sorry for the problem, I will help you fix it.